# What is the best compiler to use when you want to experiment with C++0x features?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

What is the best compiler to experiment with C++0x features? I have been experimenting with GNU g++ 4.4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Definitely **GCC Trunk**. **ConceptGCC** misses many features GCC trunk has. It is being merged into GCC currently though. It has all these features, including the new `auto`-typed variables (no new function declaration syntax yet though): http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html .

There is a GCC branch containing partial lambda support, which also contains other C++0x features. I would recommend you to try that one out too. It's in use on `#geordi at irc.freenode.org`, you can experiment with it there.

Answer (score 3):

**[Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/)** - just for trying it online

Comment: for a list of the C++0x features supported by Comeau 4.3.10.1 Beta:  http://www.comeaucomputing.com/43101features.html

Answer (score 1):

[ConceptGCC](http://www.generic-programming.org/software/ConceptGCC/) [(wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ConceptGCC) was made for that purpose, if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not the best for C++0x experimentation, but for people who are MSVC oriented, there's a "Community Tech Preview" (CTP) of VS2010 which contains a preview of VC10 that has *some* parts of C++0x implemented (note that VC10 will not have the full set of C++0x changes implemented even when VC10 is released):

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en

Some details on what's new in the VC10 CTP:

- [Visual Studio 2010 CTP released](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/visual-studio-2010-ctp-released.aspx)
- [Lambdas, auto, and static_assert: C++0x Features in VC10, Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2008/10/28/lambdas-auto-and-static-assert-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-1.aspx)

As noted in the above article, "The Visual C++ compiler in the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 September Community Technology Preview (CTP) contains support for four C++0x language features, namely:"

- lambdas,
- auto,
- static_assert,
- rvalue references